# how to find maximum value of a particular column and print the correponding row records

Tags: linux, awk

I have the following records, now I have to find the maximum value of column 4 and print the corresponding rows records.

```
2017122600|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122601|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122602|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122603|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122604|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122605|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122606|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122607|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122608|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122609|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2017122610|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Expected output is

```
2017122609|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Comment: What are you blocking on ?

Answer (score 4):

**`sort`** + **`head`** solution:

```
sort -t'|' -k4nr file | head -1
```

- `-t'|'` - treat `|` as field separator
- `-k4nr` - sort by the `4`th field numerically `n` in reverse order `r`

---

The output:

```
2017122609|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk, this will fit:

```
awk -F'|' '$4>max{max=$4;r=$0}END{print r}' file
```